# typeorm getConnection() cannot find "default" connection

Tags: connection, typeorm, nrwl-nx

I have a NX mono repo project where I want to use typeorm. The config file `ormconfig.json` is in the workspace root (same package.json folder) and this is the content:

```
{
    "name": "default",
    "type": "sqlite",
    "database": "data/db.sql",
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["libs/database/src/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}"],
    "migrations": ["libs/database/src/migrations/*.{ts,js}"],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "libs/database/src/entities",
        "migrationsDir": "libs/database/src/migrations",
        "subscribersDir": "libs/database/src/subscribers"
    }
}
```

As you can see the entities are in a database lib.

This configuration works fine for the migrations but when I try to call `getConnection()` (from anywhere, for example a node app inside the same workspace) I get the error `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`

Comment: I'm also trying to get it to work on a minimal example repo.
I'm struggeling to get the migrations to run at startup. 

Could anyone please have a look at this issue? (Link to sample repo provided)
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8219

Answer (score 4):

I have been utilizing **mono repos** for my projects too. From my experience, after searching for the same issue too before some months, I found out that you should place the `ormconfig.json` file in the top directory of your project. For example, if your directory looks like this:

```
project/
    packages/
        backend/
        common/
        frontend/
```

- And your `ormconfig.json` file is located in the `project/packages/backend/` directory, then you should move it to the at the top or parent directory, which is `project/`.
- Make sure also that your **Entities** or **Migrations** show the correct location of your entities folder in the directory path/tree. As I see you are first **build and compile** your code and then run it with `node`. So, if that is the scenario, and you do not use tools like `ts-node`, then you are correct to place the Entities or Migrations directory to point at the `lib` / `dist` / `build` folder.
- I found also helpful to use [this](https://github.com/benawad/graphql-ts-server-boilerplate/blob/master/src/utils/createTypeormConn.ts) utility function from Ben Awad, to connect TypeORM with my database. I hope it helps you too!

Comment: Hello, thank you for you suggestion.
I don't why but when I use `getConnection` it cannot file my `ormconfig.json` in the same folder of `package.json`. Instead if I use `createConnection()` it works.

Comment: Yeah, it is interesting why it does not. You can report it as an **Issue** on its GitHub repository. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please leave an upvote or accept it, I would really appreciate it.